# Why does UIPickerView show up for a text field but others do not

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

In my app I successfully linked a picker to a text field but then I had some really long pickers. So I made a custom view that is a full screen table view.  When I set a textfields inputView to my custom `UIView` it does not show up. I there anything special you have to do to make it work like a `UIPickerView`?

`SelectView` is a `UIView` component and inputView takes a `UIView`. I can not find much about this problem since I am new to iOS development and I am probably not searching for the correct thing.

SelectView consist of a label right now just so I first get the view to show up when someone clicks on a text field. Normally when you click on a textfield you can make a PickerView come up which its parent is a UIView. I want my SelectView to come up instead of the picker.

```
import UIKit

 class SelectView: UIView{
   @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
}


 let test = SelectView()
 test.tableView.delegate = self
 test.tableView.dataSource = self
 self.typeTextField.inputView = test
```

Any direction would be wonderfull

Comment: your code barely says anything. Paste more code and please try to explain what kind of functionality you want to achieve. Also what is picker? Is it UIPicker or from what I can understand is UITableView?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder/1621092-inputview?language=objc is likely what you want to look into.